# Warning: mysql_num_rows(): supplied argument is not a valid MySQL result resource - paypal donation script

Tags: php

I am getting this error in my paypal donate webpage and I am not sure how to stop it.

```
Warning: mysql_num_rows(): supplied argument is not a valid MySQL result resource in /home/sixthr6/public_html/donation/donate.php on line 116
```

I am running this is DEMO mode right now until I can find a way to get this fixed. I have a custom mySQL database setup with the correct tables so I am not sure why when I do a fake donation in DEMO mode it doesn't save the comment to the main page and just throws up that error.

Here is the code in question

```
    <?php

require "config.php";
require "connect.php";

// Determining the URL of the page:
$url = 'http://'.$_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'].dirname($_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"]);

// Fetching the number and the sum of the donations:
list($number,$sum) = mysql_fetch_array(mysql_query("SELECT COUNT(*),SUM(amount) FROM dc_donations"));

// Calculating how many percent of the goal were met:
$percent = round(min(100*($sum/$goal),100));

// Building a URL with Google's Chart API:
$chartURL = 'http://chart.apis.google.com/chart?chf=bg,s,f9faf7&amp;cht=p&amp;chd=t:'.$percent.',-'.(100-$percent).'&amp;chs=200x200&amp;chco=639600&amp;chp=1.57';

?>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Donation Center | Tutorialzine demo</title>

<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="styles.css" />

</head>

<body>

<div id="main">
    <h1>Donation Center</h1>
    <h2>Show Your Support for our Cause</h2>

    <div class="lightSection">
        <h3>Hello, dear visitor!</h3>
        <p>This is Tutorialzine's Donation Center. It utilizes PayPal's APIs to bring you a fully fledged donation solution. It is currently in <strong>Demo Mode</strong>, which means that PayPal is bypassed and you can donate as much as you want to test the functionality. You can, however, just change a variable in the config.php file to enable real donations.</p>    

        <!-- The PayPal Donation Button -->

      <form action="<?php echo $payPalURL?>" method="post" class="payPalForm">
        <div>
            <input type="hidden" name="cmd" value="_donations" />
            <input type="hidden" name="item_name" value="Donation" />

            <!-- Your PayPal email: -->
            <input type="hidden" name="business" value="<?php echo $myPayPalEmail?>" />

            <!-- PayPal will send an IPN notification to this URL: -->
            <input type="hidden" name="notify_url" value="<?php echo $url.'/ipn.php'?>" /> 

            <!-- The return page to which the user is navigated after the donations is complete: -->
            <input type="hidden" name="return" value="<?php echo $url.'/thankyou.php'?>" /> 

            <!-- Signifies that the transaction data will be passed to the return page by POST -->
            <input type="hidden" name="rm" value="2" /> 


            <!--    General configuration variables for the paypal landing page. Consult 
                    http://www.paypal.com/IntegrationCenter/ic_std-variable-ref-donate.html for more info  -->

            <input type="hidden" name="no_note" value="1" />
            <input type="hidden" name="cbt" value="Go Back To The Site" />
            <input type="hidden" name="no_shipping" value="1" />
            <input type="hidden" name="lc" value="US" />
            <input type="hidden" name="currency_code" value="USD" />


            <!-- The amount of the transaction: -->

            <select name="amount">
                <option value="50">$50</option>
                <option value="20">$20</option>
                <option value="10" selected="selected">$10</option>
                <option value="5">$5</option>
                <option value="2">$2</option>
                <option value="1">$1</option>
            </select>

            <input type="hidden" name="bn" value="PP-DonationsBF:btn_donate_LG.gif:NonHostedGuest" />

            <!-- You can change the image of the button: -->
            <input type="image" src="https://www.paypal.com/en_US/i/btn/btn_donate_LG.gif" name="submit" alt="PayPal - The safer, easier way to pay online!" />

          <img alt="" src="https://www.paypal.com/en_US/i/scr/pixel.gif" width="1" height="1" />
        </div>
        </form>

    </div>

    <!-- Setting the Google Chart API address as the background image of the div: -->

    <div class="chart" style="background:url('<?php echo $chartURL?>');">
        Our Goal
    </div>

    <div class="donations">
        <?php echo $percent?>% done
    </div>


    <div class="clear"></div>

    <div class="donors">
        <h3>The Donor List</h3>
        <h4>Folks Who Showed Their Support</h4>

        <div class="comments">

        <?php
            $comments = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM dc_comments ORDER BY id DESC");

            // Building the Donor List:

            if(mysql_num_rows($comments)) 
            {
                while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($comments))
                {
                    ?>

                        <div class="entry">
                            <p class="comment">
                            <?php 
                                echo nl2br($row['message']); // Converting the newlines of the comment to <br /> tags
                            ?>
                            <span class="tip"></span>
                            </p>

                            <div class="name">
                                <?php echo $row['name']?> <a class="url" href="<?php echo $row['url']?>"><?php echo $row['url']?></a>
                            </div>
                        </div>

                    <?php
                }
            }
        ?>


        </div> <!-- Closing the comments div -->

    </div> <!-- Closing the donors div -->

</div> <!-- Closing the main div -->


</body>
</html>
```

I am using the coding from this website http://tutorialzine.com/2010/05/donation-center-php-mysql-paypal-api/ and their demo is working fine but when I use mine and set it up how they have their it's still throwing the error.

Comment: what is the value of $comments ?

Comment: Before doing anything, remove **all** instances of the silence operator (`@`). We cannot help you if you simply suppress errors that tell you what is happening.

Comment: dont use mysql_* its deprecated use PDO or mysqli instead

Comment: your query, that num rows is using, failed, debug that

Comment: I removed all the @ now i am receiving this error Warning: mysql_fetch_array(): supplied argument is not a valid MySQL result resource in /home/sixthr6/public_html/donation/donate.php on line 10

Comment: looks like your query is failing...try to run the query directly in dba admin, and show us what error are you getting

Comment: http://uk3.php.net/mysql_error you need to find out what the error is

Comment: You should also split `mysql_fetch_array(mysql_query(` into separate statements; you are currently assuming the query will always return a result-set, rather than false.

Comment: I am not really sure on how to do that as I did not write the script I am using only following a tutorial on how to do it.

Comment: See [the docs](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-query.php), there are examples there.

Comment: You *really* need to use `mysql_error` to print out the error in your query. There's not much we (and you) can do without proper errors.

Comment: Warning: mysql_fetch_array(): supplied argument is not a valid MySQL result resource in /home/sixthr6/public_html/donation/donate.php on line 10
No database selected

Answer (score -2):

This line renders the error:

```
list($number,$sum) = mysql_fetch_array(mysql_query("SELECT COUNT(*),SUM(amount) FROM dc_donations"));
```

First of all, enter

```
SELECT COUNT(*),SUM(amount) FROM dc_donations
```

in phpMyAdmin. Does this render an error too?

Does `dc_donations` exist and does it has an `amount` field?

**Please check errors**

One way to check error is like this:

```
$donationQuery = "SELECT COUNT(*),SUM(amount) FROM dc_donations";

$cursor = mysql_query( $donationQuery );
assert( ! mysql_errno() );
assert( is_resource( $cursor ));

list($number,$sum) = mysql_fetch_array( $cursor );
```

See the `assert()` function call? This function evaluates its parameter. If it doesn't evaluate to TRUE, it prints an error message. [assert() docs](http://php.net/manual/en/function.assert.php).

**Hint for your next question**

Your code-sample contains **huge amounts of irrelevant information**. All those HTML-code isn't relevant regarding your problem.

For finding the root cause, it would be wise to **reduce the amount of code** in your file. Likewise, you question is likely to get much more answers too - *no one wants to search for relevant PHP-code in code-samples*.

Comment: I used this script to setup the table and it does have an amount field  

    CREATE TABLE `dc_donations` (
  `transaction_id` varchar(64) collate utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL default '',
  `donor_email` varchar(255) collate utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL default '',
  `amount` double NOT NULL default '0',
  `original_request` text collate utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `dt` timestamp NOT NULL default CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  PRIMARY KEY  (`transaction_id`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci;

Comment: Yoda comparisons? This is PHP. `mysql_error() = 0` would be an error because you can't set a function to 0.

Comment: Probably because you answered a bad question?

Comment: You use Yoda comparisons (`0 == mysql_error()`). The reason is to prevent people typing `mysql_error() == 0` from typing `mysql_error() = 0`.

Comment: Yes. Every _modern_ compiler warns you of them. There is no need.

Comment: Well that's why I downvoted. My votes. I disagree with the reasoning behind them. I think they are crap.

Comment: Ok. I have removed my downvote. If you delete your comments regarding this issue, I will to.

Comment: Hey folks, I even removed the Yodaism. What's now wrong? Why down vote?